# SQL Query Filtering COUNT without using HAVING

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm having trouble with this SQL query.  My goal is the retrieve the ContactIDs of Contacts who live in CT or MA and have had more than 2 events.

Here is the query I'm trying to use:

```
SELECT `Contacts`.`ContactID`
FROM (`Contacts`)
JOIN `Events` ON `Contacts`.`ContactID` = `Events`.`ContactID`
JOIN `Contact_Addresses` ON `Contacts`.`ContactID` = `Contact_Addresses`.`ContactID`
WHERE `Contact_Addresses`.`State` IN ('CT', 'MA') AND COUNT(Events.EventID) > 2
```

I know I could use the group by statement HAVING. Like so:

```
...WHERE `Contact_Addresses`.`State` IN ('CT', 'MA')
HAVING COUNT(Events.EventID) > 2
```

But this doesn't give me the correct results that I'm looking for.  I know I'm close, I think maybe I need a subquery added in?  Any guidance in the direction I should go would be a huge help.

Answer (score 2):

> ...this doesn't give me the correct results that I'm looking for.

That doesn't give us any idea what the problem is.

Use:

```
SELECT c.contactid
  FROM CONTACTS c
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                FROM EVENTS e
               WHERE e.contactid = c.contactid
            GROUP BY e.eventid
              HAVING COUNT(e.eventid) > 2)
   AND EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                FROM CONTACT_ADDRESSES ca 
               WHERE ca.contactid = c.contactid
                 AND ca.state IN ('CT', 'MA'))
```

Comment: Sorry for the poor description of the results.  I knew that the results I was receiving were in-accurate.  Thank you for the query help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a `GROUP BY` clause as well, otherwise `COUNT(Events.EventID)` will be returning `1` in all cases:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
JOIN ....
WHERE ...
GROUP BY Events.ContactID
```

You only need to use backticks on your field names if they happen to be a reserved word, fyi.

Comment: I'm voting this up because I agree with the suggested change. However, I think you are mistaken in your explanation of the current issue. Without a GROUP BY, the OP's current query can only return at most 1 row. (A HAVING without a GROUP BY implies the "grand total" GROUP BY, which returns a single row normally but the HAVING may filter it down to 0.)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your query to:

```
SELECT `Contacts`.`ContactID`
FROM (`Contacts`)
JOIN `Events` ON `Contacts`.`ContactID` = `Events`.`ContactID`
JOIN `Contact_Addresses` ON `Contacts`.`ContactID` = `Contact_Addresses`.`ContactID`
WHERE `Contact_Addresses`.`State` IN ('CT', 'MA')
GROUP BY `Contacts`.`ContactID`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Events.EventID) > 2
```

You need to group on ContactID to count the number of events per contact, and you need to count **distinct** EventID values in case a Contact has more than one address in CT or MA.